Interactive Email: AMPScript on Cloud Page not executing
I am trying out interactive email for the first time - so far, its cool - but my company is a global company which means I need the labels for the form to be able to support multiple languages.
The way I typically achieve this is by storing the content in a DE with the dialect as the primary key, putting a lookupRows() in the email and setting each column from the DE as a variable - then using %%=v()=%% or treatAsContent to print the content from the DE.
This all works great-- except for the failover page -- even the failover button label wont execute.
I tried adding the same lookupRows() on the Interactive Cloud Page too, but that also does not work.
Finally I thought, well, the view in browser executes the AMPscript so I'll make a content block with a button that has VAWP for the href but that failover block won't even save in the form.
Any suggestions on how to make this multilingual that doesn't mean I build the form 34 times for all the dialects we support? - for that, I'll just custom code this whole thing...

If by failover you are talking about fallback page, then yes, I would redirect contact to a separate cloudpage where I would custom code the fallback form from the scratch, similar like you described.
Although, I dont see why would you have to recreate the form 34 times if only the fallback page is affected by the problem...
I know this doesnt answer your question directly, but sometimes having more control and custom coding is not a bad thing for future flexibility.
